# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (fetch error)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a fetch request and it works fine. My question is when I try to log a returned data from a nested function I get error `Unexpected end of JSON input`. How can I fetch a returned data from a nested function? My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function callFun() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:PORT/api/routePath`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.line)
     }
}

callFun()
```

```js
function fun1() {
    function fun2() {
        const line = "this is line"
        return {line}
    }
}



function callFun1() {
    const data1 = fun1()
    return data1
}

module.exports = {callFun1};
```

Comment: what im trying to do with ```callFun1``` is return the data that is in ```fun2``` which is ```line```.@JaromandaX

Comment: that is what I did when i returned ```data1```  in ```callFun1```@JaromandaX

Comment: I wouldn't be able to set ```data1 = fun2``` because ```fun2``` can't be accessed globally. That's where I got stuck too.@JaromandaX

Comment: This is an example code I provided. The actual code contains multiple nested functions with return statements. This is a minified question. The workaround you suggested removed the error. I'm currently trying to log ```line``` on client side don't know why it's not working.@JaromandaX

Comment: yet another barrier. Any more workaround suggestions?@JaromandaX

Comment: It's totally unclear what your two snippets have to do with each other, and how your fetch request works fine and throws an error at the same time.

Comment: my fetch request works fine as in the routes and server is configured correctly. What I'm trying to do is access the returned data ```line``` on the front end with my fetch request. To explain it in simpler terms.@Bergi

Comment: What is the content of the response? Why is `callFun1` an async function?

Comment: it is an async function because it needs to await for ```Fun1```.@jabaa

Comment: A function can only be awaited, if it returns a promise. None of your functions does, though

Comment: Btw, You should `return fun2()` inside fun1, this would give you access to the return value of fun2 outside of fun1, if you call fun1()

Comment: my original code has a promise in it that needs to be awaited but this minified code doesn't need an await I have edited the code above.@devnull69

Comment: You haven't answered my question. _"What is the content of the response?"_ You're trying to parse the content as JSON data but it looks like the response doesn't contain JSON.

Comment: Hey @jabaa the question I'm stuck on is more complicated than the question here to be frank. I can push a commit of a portion of the code I'm using to GitHub if can take a look at it.

Comment: If your question can't be asked on Stack Overflow it's off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the response you are getting is in json format. If it in array or any other format it will throw error while parsing.

Comment: I parsed my response to JSON in my fetch request.@anand govind c g